# Travelling salesman tips

Tags: algorithm, optimization, traveling-salesman

I'm developing an application in which I have to face the travelling salesman problem. I did my own tries but the times I'm getting are really bad. I was searching some optimization solutions but I'm not getting anything clear.

Any tips to start a optimization of this process or algorythms? My current algorithm is the basic backtracking one.

My graph satisfy all the typical conditions in a TSP graph (no directional, simetric, conex)...

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to optimize something you can't see. What does your current algorithm do?

Comment: Sorry. My current algorithm is the basic backtracking one, so I'm navegation to all nodes... but I pode when the actual path is heavier than the minimum I have saved.

Comment: Do you know anything about the distances?  Do they obey the triangle inequality (that is, distance from a to c is at most distance from a to b plus distance from b to c)?  Or are they totally arbitrary?

Comment: Yes, it obey that. The points to pass are cities. The app is for drivers who needs to visit a group of warehouses... so the weights are the distances between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your metric satisfy the triangle inequality I can suggest you to look for the christofides algorithm. It has a guarantee to be within the optimum solution. IMO the difficult part about christofides algorithm is the perfect matching. If you don't care about a guarantee you can look for the google map tsp solver. It uses the Ant Colony Optimization for large route. If you want really fast solving and less accuracy you can look for a monster curve for example a hilbert curve or a moore curve.

Comment: Thanks. It's an android gps application in which I have to visit some points... Maybe I have to use less accuracy because others ones probably will consume a lot of battery...